# Android studio how to use one recycleview for more than one view?

Tags: android-studio

I have a `search fragment` which allow users to search for both users and posts. Here is the XML:

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/search_bar"
        android:background="@drawable/white_rounded"
        android:hint="Search for users or recipes ..."
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:inputType="textFilter"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:lines="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
<!-- android:digits="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890" -->
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <com.taimoorsikander.myapplication.Widgets.B_RecycleView
        android:id="@+id/recycle_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bar" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycle_view2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_50sdp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bar" />
```

and in my `SearchFragment` I implemented the search like this:

```
public class SearchFragment extends Fragment {
    private B_RecycleView recyclerView;
    private SearchAdapter searchAdapter;
    private List<User> mUsers;
  // for posts
    EditText search_bar;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView2;
    DatabaseReference DataRef;
    private List<Post> mPosts;
    PostSearchAdapter postSearchAdapter;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);
        DataRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("posts");
        recyclerView2 = view.findViewById(R.id.recycle_view2);
        search_bar = view.findViewById(R.id.search_bar);
        recyclerView2.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        recyclerView2.setHasFixedSize(true);
         mPosts = new ArrayList<>();
         postSearchAdapter = new PostSearchAdapter(getContext(), mPosts);
         recyclerView2.setAdapter(postSearchAdapter);
          readPosts();
         search_bar.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            if(s.toString().isEmpty()) {
                mPosts.clear();
                recyclerView2.removeAllViews();
             //   recyclerView2.hideIfEmpty(recyclerView2);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (!s.toString().isEmpty()) {
                searchPosts(s.toString().toLowerCase());
            }else
            {
                mPosts.clear();
                recyclerView2.removeAllViews();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(s.toString().isEmpty()) {
                mPosts.clear();
                recyclerView2.removeAllViews();
            }

        }
    });

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycle_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        search_bar = view.findViewById(R.id.search_bar);
        mUsers = new ArrayList<>();
        searchAdapter = new SearchAdapter(getContext(), mUsers);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(searchAdapter);
        readUsers();
        search_bar.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                if(s.toString().isEmpty()) {
                    mUsers.clear();
                    recyclerView.removeAllViews();
                    recyclerView.hideIfEmpty(recyclerView);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (!s.toString().isEmpty()) {
                    searchUsers(s.toString().toLowerCase());
                }else
                    {
                        mUsers.clear();
                        recyclerView.removeAllViews();
                    }
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if(s.toString().isEmpty()) {
                    mUsers.clear();
                    recyclerView.removeAllViews();
                }

            }
        });
```

and I used two adapters since I'm using two different things in the search (post and users). it is working now but the problem is that it doesn't look neat having two separate `recyclerViews`. is there a way to merge them ? I want them to be in one view. is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few alternative, but if you didn't want to reinvent the wheel, try to use the following approach:

Have a different item or layout (views):

> tl;dr if you want to build a layout-like a Playstore homepage or AirBnb hotel list

Android has `ConcatAdapter` [see here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/merge-adapters-sequentially-with-mergeadapter-294d2942127a)

Also, to have a better understanding about the multiple view adapter, see recommended article [here](https://medium.com/@anangkur/bfa0c48b43b4),

> tl;dr: Adapter delegate purpose was similar to `ConcatAdapter` to have a composite (or multiple) `RecyclerView` (with different layout adapter in 1 RecyclerView)

> Inspired by: http://hannesdorfmann.com/android/adapter-delegates/

Answer (score 1):

Since you've already created two adapters you can call them conditionally on the single RecyclerView; like if the search query is for posts call posts-adapter and if the the search query is for users then call users-adapter.